# Google Analytics - multiple domains tracking - linked to webmaster tools

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm currently tracking multiple domains through Google Analytics but the "Query" report is still empty since I must link **one single** webmaster tool property.

This doesn't make any sense to me since my Multiple Tracking Profile, pulls data from 6 different websites.

Is there a way to merge all the webmaster-tool-query-data of all the domains involved into the Google Multiple domain tracking report?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there can only be a one-to-one mapping:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006

> Note: A site can be associated with only one web property, and vice
>   versa. Creating a new association removes the previously existing
>   association.